# iOS Programmatically go to Tab AND Push View Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

My app is connected with Facebook Deep Link for Open Graph.  When the open graph story is clicked in Facebook app, it goes back to my app.  I want it to go back to my app in the 2nd tab, and subsequently present a new view controller onto the screen.

In my appDelegate, when the action is completed from Facebook, I have:

```
 NSString *objectId = [[[call appLinkData] targetURL].path substringFromIndex:1];
 NSString *nameofhtml = [[objectId lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
// now handle the deep link
// write whatever code you need to show a view controller that displays the object, etc.

      if (_webViewController == nil) {
          self.webViewController = [[PrayerGifts alloc] init];
       }
     _webViewController.fromFacebook = nameofhtml;
      [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
      [_webViewController viewPrayer];
```

This successfully sets the tab where I want it, but the method in _webViewController named viewPrayer never gets called.  That method is:

```
Prayer *gonow = [[Prayer alloc] init];
    gonow.currentURL = fromFacebook;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gonow animated:YES];
    [gonow release];
```

How can I get it to come back into the app, change the tab bar, and launch the correct view from that tab

Comment: Your question isn't understandable. Is the question why isn't viewPrayer  getting called, or is it how to get it to come back (whatever "it" is and whatever "come back" means, neither of which isn't clear what these are, nor what is the focus of the question).

Comment: @MartinH see my edited question for clarification.

Comment: From the code there's no reason why viewPrayer is not getting called, therefore I doubt the code you have posted is being executed. How have you confirmed its not getting called? Have you put a breakpoint in viewPrayer and another at the line [_webViewController viewPrayer]?

Comment: I haven't been able to use the console.  Everytime I run it on my 5S, it installs it and runs, but Xcode never detects that, and ends the debug sessino

Comment: Its a bit pointless posting a question at the moment, you need to first learn how to debug using Xcode. The code you posted isn't even being called (I mean the first bit of code), so that is obviously why viewPrayer is not getting called. Nobody can answer why not. You have to learn how to debug code and learn how to use Xcode, then come have here if you have more info.

Comment: If I could answer the question "Why is this code not being called" I wouldn't have asked the question, "Why is this code not working"  I am asking why it is not getting called.

Comment: @MartinH I got Xcode working better.  I added an NSLog in viewPrayer method.  The method is definitely getting called, it's just not performing right.

Comment: Or it was showing up in the NSLog, but not it isn't again.

Comment: "Why is this code not being called". You asked why is viewPrayer not getting called. I answered that viewPrayer is not getting called because the code that is calling it is itself not getting called (i.e. the code in the first block in your question is not itself getting called). There, question answered. As to why the code that is calling viewPraryer is itself not getting called is impossible to answer as there is no code showing how that code is called. I'd recommend starting a new question showing more context and code so its possible to get a bigger picture of how your app is behaving.

Comment: @MartinH that code IS GETTING CALLED.  In that whole block, every line of code is called EXCEPT viewPrayer

Comment: Check _webViewController is not nil at the point of the call. You are assigning the alloc result to self.webViewController, not to _webViewController. They presumably are the same but maybe not if there is something unconventional in the way you have declared them.

Comment: If _webViewController is not nil, there there is no explanation for why viewPrayer is not getting called. Unless the viewPrayer method does not exist for a class of type PrayerGifts. But if that were the case you would be getting a runtime error with an "unrecognized selector" message in Xcode.

Comment: Header file declares in the iVar as _webViewController with property of _webViewController and I synthesize webViewController = _webViewController

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3.1

```
func goToChatViewController(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
        if let storyboard = self.storyboard {
            let helpViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HelpViewController") as! HelpViewController
            let settingsRootNavigationController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![3] as! UINavigationController

            settingsRootNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
            settingsRootNavigationController.pushViewController(chatController, animated: true)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem today and found a simple solution that worked for me. I have a TabBarController with 4 tabs. I need to get from a deep view controller hierarchy in tab 2 to a nested view controller in tab 4. Here is how I do it.

```
  func goToHelpViewController(){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
                let settingsStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "SettingsSection", bundle: nil)
                let helpViewController = settingsStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HelpViewController") as! HelpViewController
                let settingsRootNavigationController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![3] as! UINavigationController

      settingsRootNavigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
                settingsRootNavigationController.pushViewController(helpViewController, animated: true)
            })
        }
```

I tested this and you must set the selected index before getting the navigation controller from the desired tab. After setting the index, you get the navigation controller for the desired tab and push it onto your navigation controller stack for the desired tab.The reason I call `popToRootViewController` on settingsRootNavigationController is to always keep that stack fresh on the first view controller in its navigation stack. However, your requirements for that may not be the same as mine.